# Selecting specific cells from a column in excel based on another column

Tags: excel, reference, cells

Here is the table that I am trying to reference from:

```
**A**         **B**
----------------------
TRUE          ID 100
FALSE         0
FALSE         0
FALSE         0
FALSE         0
TRUE          ID 811
FALSE         0
FALSE         0
FALSE         0
TRUE          ID 742
```

Basically all I want be able to do here is to list the cells in row B where row A is true. Or even where row B is not 0. So the result should look like this:

```
**A**          
ID 100
ID 811
ID 742
```

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this but I can't seem to work it out?

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF( A1,1,"")
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2,1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **C** "marks" the desired values. Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>MAX(C:C),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0)))
```

and copy down.  An example:

[image]

Note:

This method avoids using an array formula.

**EDIT#1:**

If you don't mind *array formula*s, then in **C1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15,ROW($A$1:$A$15)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$15))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

and copy down.

*Array formulas* must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.